# View Available Package (out-of-scope) Updates with Composer

Tags: version, composer-php

Is there a way to see when a composer package has an available update that is higher than its composer.json requirement allows?

---

My composer.son file has require statements like this:

```
"require" : {
    "components/bootstrap"         : "~3.3.4",
    "components/jquery"            : "~1.11.2",
    "erusev/parsedown"             : "~1.5.2",
    ...
},
```

Imagine parsedown has just had a big jump in functionality, and moved to version 2.0.0. When I run a composer update, as expected, my app will not be updated to version 2.0.0 (if one existed). Is there a way I can see that 2.0.0 is available with a composer command?

I am worried I might miss some updates, because I have locked down my required versions so much, and hope there is some command or way to see all of the available updates for my composer packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to see when a composer package has an available update that is higher than its composer.json requirement allows?

Yes, there is a way. It's basically the comparison of the defined version constraint in your composer.json with the version numbers of `composer show` for the specific package.

1. `composer show --self`

This shows you the output of composer.json of your project.
You get the defined version constraints.
Alternatively, just open composer.json.

2. `composer show --installed`

This shows you the resolved and installed versions.

3. `composer show package/package`

This shows you all available version numbers.

Sidenote: `composer show erusev/parsedown` says there is no v2.0.0 release, yet.

---

There isn't a table display for this, yet, but it's a nice feature request, because it eases project maintenance. But assembling the infos automatically is quite resource intensive, especially when there are a lot of packages.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| package          | defined constraint | current version | available versions     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| erusev/parsedown | ~1.0               | 1.5.2           | dev-master, v1.5.2, ...|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I just noticed, doing a `composer show package/package` command will indicate the list of available versions as well as the installed version in green with and asterisk!

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend relaxing your version requirements to only have tilde-two-numbers instead of three, and see how it goes. It will allow you to not only get patch updates, but also compatible feature updates.

Composer currently has no way to signal to you the presence of incompatible versions beyond the original package being flagged "abandoned". You have to monitor the release announcement of the packages you use manually, or you could try and see what happens if you add the next major version to the requirement: `"erusev/parsedown" : "~1.5.2|~2.0"`

This however looks strange if you haven't even tried to update to the latest 1.x version using `"erusev/parsedown" :"^1.5.2"`. Note that the caret is a shortcut for `~1.5,>=1.5.2` for major versions >= 1 (major versions 0.x are handled more strictly).